# Vaadin component visible event

Tags: vaadin

Is there an event, or some other way, to know when a vaadin component becomes visible in the browser? This is not for hidden components. I mean when the component is off canvas, like in a different tab that is not selected. Or may be way down the page.

Comment: for tabs there are tabchange events (tabs are done on "server").

Answer (score 1):

It may be late but i started to create a Vaadin add-on that wraps the jQuery Waypoints library so that You can listen to Vaadin components becoming visible by scrolling.

You can find an experimental release here:

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/waypoints-add-on

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it but maybe you can use `jQuery Waypoints`.